# Refactoring in two thousand lines of code xaml page

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, refactoring

My page has 5 tab items and there are over two thousand lines of code. Is it possible to move the code of each tab item to some kind of template? How can I refactor such a big page?

Thank you.

Comment: put each tab page in a usercontrol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just create new UserControls and put the content for each tab page in them

```
<UserControl x:Class="InstrumentServiceTabItems.ServiceHistory">
    <Grid>
    ...
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and then on main page include ref as follow:

```
<Page x:Class="InstrumentServicePage"
      xmlns:sHistory="clr-namespace:InstrumentServiceTabItems">

        <TabControl>
            <TabItem>
               <sHistory:ServiceHistory />
            <TabItem>
        </TabControl>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could always just create new resource dictionaries and put the content for each tab page in them giving them a key.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Grid x:Key="tabPage1">
        <!-- your controls here-->
    </Grid>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

then reference with that key.

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Content="{StaticResource tabPage1}"/>
</TabControl>
```

if you want to use the content on multiple tabs it will actually share the same static instance so you'll have to specify  if you want multiple instances of it.